# TFS auto merge picking the wrong code

Tags: tfs, conflict, automerge

We are a small team using TFS express 2012. While merging a changeset to the another branch I encountered a conflict.  When I chose the merge tool to resolve the conflicts I noticed it has auto merged some of them but with the older code. what can be the cause of this issue. here is more details:
Dev is branched into 2 : release and feature1. developer A has done some development on dev when we branched feature1 and release.developer B starts working on feature1. developer A continues working on dev at the same time. after feature1 is done we merge back to dev. no issues up to here. when we want to merge the changes from dev into release a conflict happens in developer A code and the auto merge picks the code from release, not the dev which has the newer code. So in the release developer is losing the new code

Answer (score 1):

I investigated and found what was wrong. Just tried to merge a later changeset without merging the earlier ones. the code I was looking for was in an earlier changeset. 
After applying the earlier changeset everything is fine.[missed an obvious behaviour]

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is merge from Dev to Release, Dev is Source Branch, and Release is Target Branch. If you want the changes in Dev, you need to take Source Branch Version when there is a conflict.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. What you said is another option. My question is  when using the merge tool, why TFS chose the older code and overwrote the newer code confidently. when I annotate the same line of code in target and source the target changeset is 197 and the source is 245 but TFS chose the code in target whih is 197. I want to know what I have done wrong